# Changing Button Color When Hovering Over Background DIV (CSS)

Tags: css, button, colors, background, hover

Apologies if there should already be a solution to this, however, I've searched everything and couldn't find a fix for this particular issue.

I have the following (simplified) scenario:  a background image (::after) with a button on it.

```
.background::after {
opacity: .5;
}

.background:hover::after {
opacity: 1;
}

.button {
color: #000;
}
```

Now what I would like to achieve is to change the button color from black to white when hovering over the background.

I was hoping something like this would work but it doesn't:

```
.background:hover::after > .button {
color: #fff;
}
```

Even though I've been successful with similar tasks in the past, right now I'm at a loss, however obvious it should be actually.  I'm probably missing something.

Can someone put me in the right direction?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, my bad.  It's working without the pseudo element, of course:

```
.background:hover .button {
color: #fff;
}
```